# Rebind event within collection.fetch success callback

Tags: backbone.js

In my view, I have following bindings:

```
events: 
{
     'click #showallconsumers': 'showAllConsumers',
     'submit form': 'submit',
     'click #allconsumerstable tbody tr': 'selectConsumer',
},
```

In showAllConsumers function, I need to disable click on #showallconsumers anchor, fetch collection and rebind click event on #showconsumers after fetching finished.

```
showAllConsumers: function()
{       
    $(this.el).undelegate('#showallconsumers', 'click');

    this.collection.fetch(({async: true, success : this.renderAllConsumers}));

},
renderAllConsumers: function(collection)
{
     //i'm populating table with data from collection 

     $('#showallconsumers').bind('click', this.showAllConsumers);
},
```

When I click on #showallconsumers anchor, undelegate works, but when fetching is finished, .bind(...) can not rebind event. I also tried with .delegate(...).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `success` function of `fetch` isn't getting called with the view as its context, so `this.showAllConsumers` isn't pointing to your function.

When calling `fetch` wrap the `success` function in [Underscore's `bind`](http://underscorejs.org/#bind) so that `this` points to your view:

```
this.collection.fetch(({async: true, success : _.bind(this.renderAllConsumers, this)}));
```